# How does from ... import ... statement import global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't figure out how does it works under the hood.
I have following files:

test.py

```
x = 20

def foo():
    print x
```

test2.py

```
from test import foo

foo()
```

When I import the foo function in test2.py how does it resolves x. As far as I know the statement *from test import foo* imports only the foo function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions retain a reference to their module globals. `foo` has such a reference:

```
>>> from test import foo
>>> foo.__globals__
{'x': 20, 'foo': <function foo at 0x102f3d410, ...}
```

What happens is that Python creates a module *object* when you import something; this object is stored in `sys.modules` and it serves as the global namespace for that module. The `import` statement then binds names in your 'local' module to either that same object or to attributes of that object.

Functions reference the same namespace for looking up globals from where they were defined; they essentially reference the same dictionary object:

```
>>> import sys
>>> foo.__globals__ is sys.modules['test'].__dict__
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got an additional question. Let's say I have added the second function in test called bar. In test2 I use the same from import statement. I cannot evaluate the function (as I imported only foo) but it exists in sys.modules['test'].__dict__ isn't it redundant information ?

Comment: @AdrianBaran: You mean that `bar` plays no role and just sits there referenced by the module object? What if other code were to import it later on? Also, Python cannot know if `foo` will ever use it at some point. If you feel it would be redundant, move it to a separate module. But function objects take minimal memory, I would not worry about that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean @Martijn Pieters. I agree that it might be helpful for antoher code to import it later on. It would be more straightforward for me if the from import statement imports only one function and import statement alone imports the whole module. With your help I have discovered that I can do sth like this sys.modules['test'].__dict__['boo']() and so use all the functions in the specific module even if I have used from import statement. Before I misunderstood it.

Comment: @AdrianBaran: the thing with globals is that until code executes, Python cannot know beforehand what is used and what is not. You can do `for name, obj in globals().items(): if callable(obj): print 'calling', name, 'gives', obj()` for example.

Comment: @AdrianBaran: as such *all* of the module is imported. `from module import name` still has to import and execute the whole module, before then creating a new reference to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

This thing, when function remembers all environment in wich it was defined is called [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: Note that in Python, the term *closure* is used only for non-local names that are taken from surrounding scopes that are not the global scope.

Comment: Global names are looked up at runtime, what will be resolved as a closure is pre-determined at compile time.